# YAML Powershell to Update File Permissions Failing

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

Azure DevOps is overwriting the file permissions on a needed web file.  So, I decided to add a step in my YAML Pipeline that ensures the files permissions are always set correctly.

I tested it on the server using the Command Line Tool (CMD) & it works great. However, I added the Step into my YAML & I get the following exception.

> The term 'RX' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
> script

- Is there something wrong with my YAML's command-line?

**USING THE COMMAND LINE TOOL (CMD):**
This is the RAW command-line I tested using CMD...it works fine...and the [(RX) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls)  is correct.

```
icacls "D:\Applications\MyApplication\bin\Select.Html.dep" /grant:r "mydomain\my_ServiceAccountName_DEV":(RX)
```

**THE YAML PIPELINE:**
The command line (itself) is obviously running in PowerShell.  But I am new to YAML...so perhaps the formatting is off (a bit).  Can someone help please?

```
#-------------------------------------
#Update File-Permissions for ServiceAccount
- stage: Update_File_Permissions
  jobs:
  - deployment: Update_File_Permissions
    displayName: Update File Permissions
    environment:
      name: 'Purposely Omitted'
      resourceType: 'VirtualMachine'
      tags: 'Purposely Omitted'
    variables:
      DevAppFolder: 'Purposely Omitted'

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                d:
                cmd /c icacls "D:\Applications\MyApplication\bin\Select.Html.dep" /grant:r "mydomain\my_ServiceAccountName_DEV":(RX)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recommend you use the 'Command Line' task instead of the 'PowerShell' task to run your script:

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: |
        d:
        icacls "D:\ttt\23.txt" /grant:r "mydomain\mylocaluername":(RX)
```

It works well on my test:
[image]